# Need to turn WiFi on and off on devices so pages load

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Since I changed my broadband provider a weird thing has been happening: for many times a day, suddenly, even though on my devices it shows I'm properly connected to my WiFi, pages or apps simply won't load, but if I turn their WiFi connection off and back on again, then I have data connection again.

It's happening with all my devices (PC, iPhone, Macbook, Android, etc), and in separate moments, meaning for example pages won't load on my iPhone, but will load on my PC, or MacBook.

Does anyone can give me a lead on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

> It's happening with all my devices (PC, iPhone, Macbook, Android, etc)

You most likely need to refresh or reset the DNS address in your Modem (Modem / Router).

Contact your ISP and ask them for the DNS settings in your Modem and make sure the settings are correct.

Once done, restart your Modem (Modem / Router).

Since all devices are affected, you need to make sure the main modem has been properly set.

If your Wi-Fi router is separate (probably not likely), you will need to reset it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have three separate devices, one in which the fiber cable get connected to (the modem, I guess). Connected to it there's another larger one which apparently is the router, and then what I believe to be a signal repeater, sitting in the living room. There's also the TV decoder, which I believe gets its signal from the router, wirelessly. I'll get in touch with my ISP, thanks again!